# Remove item from ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

In following code, I want to remove items which are null or size of arraylist is zero from ArrayList in first "for loop". After running first loop, again I  have a second loop. In second loop, I have tested whether it contains any item which is null or size of item is zero. Although I erase in first loop, ArrayList BS contains items which was deleted from list.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Record>> BS = new ArrayList<>(); 
.
.// some codes
.

for (int j = 0; j < BS.size(); j++) {
    if(BS.get(j) == null || BS.get(j).size() == 0){
        BS.remove(j);
    }
}


for (int j = 0; j < BS.size(); j++) {
    if(BS.get(j) == null || BS.get(j).size() == 0){
            System.out.println("Again, fall into if condition");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you've got here is that you won't check the item immediately after the one you removed.

Either:

```
BS.removeIf(a -> a == null || a.isEmpty());
```

Or iterate the list in reverse:

```
for (int j = BS.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) { ... }
```

Or use an `Iterator`, and use the `remove()` method.

```
Iterator<? extends List<Record>> it = BS.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  List<Record> list = it.next();
  if (list == 0 || list.isEmpty()) it.remove();
}
```

`removeIf` is the best approach, as it is optimized to know how to remove many elements efficiently: removing anything but the last element of an `ArrayList` requires all of the elements with greater index to be shifted along in the internal array, so removing elements by simply calling `remove` is quadratic in time complexity.

However, it is available in Java 8+ only. (You can implement the efficient removal quite easily in earlier versions of Java; it's just a little more work).

Answer (score 1):

When removing items from an Array, usually you want to go from the last item to the first one, otherwwise your index will jump one item each time you do a remove.

This because removing an item shifts the remaining ones back of one position, namely from position "j + 1" to position j. So the next loop you skip the item a position j (that's the item that was in position j+1 in the previous loop).

Try this:

```
for (int j = BS.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if(BS.get(j) == null || BS.get(j).size() == 0){
        BS.remove(j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when a item is removed next item will not be removed if the condition is true. For that you should decrement the index when you remove an item.

Change as follow.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Record>> BS = new ArrayList<>(); 
.
.// some codes
.

for (int j = 0; j < BS.size(); j++) {
    if(BS.get(j) == null || BS.get(j).size() == 0){
        BS.remove(j);
        j--;
    }
}
```